# After remove app, can I use same bundle ID?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bundle

XCODE 4.3.2 
Mac OS X 10.7.3

I have done `developer reject` because of small error after registering app.
When I try to register again, it occurred "*`An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store`*" and failed to submit.
So, I removed app and tried to register app again.

Then, there is error message like this:

```
The following error(s) occurred:
- The Bundle ID you entered has already been used.
- The App Name you entered has already been used.
```

Can I register again by same name? What do I have to do for this?

And I made App ID "com.www.aaabbb" to use PUSH.
After remove app, I can't find this Bundle ID. And error occurred.

How may I use this Bundle ID?

This is very serious problem to me. Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you have `rejected Binary`, than you can upload it again by going in and Click `"Ready To upload Binary"`.

If you have `deleted the application` than thats really serious problem as **`APPLE does not allow`** using same bundle id to create application as it counts that bundle as used.

You have to `create new Bundle ID` and configure it for Push Notification.

Comment: Does this mean that a non releas version of an app can be uploaded just to check if it'll pass Apple requirements? For instance, if we have a version of an app that just need some interface changes, could we submit it, in case of being approved reject the binary and upload it again when the final version is ready?

Comment: yes certainly you can check like that. But remember don't delete application. Only Reject binary and you can upload it again.